# Enable 'show available tokens' in Webform 8.x?

Tags: token, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I'm using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) 8.x-5.0-beta13, and I'm not seeing the "show available tokens" when editing the settings for the default email to send. Is there something I'm missing to enable this functionality?

Comment: Can anyone clarify for me why this got a downvote? It's a legitimate situation that Drupal developers could run into - wanting to enable the 'show available tokens' when using the Webform module. True, I should have tied together the different theories better, but I could see this being an 'aha' moment for some other Drupal developer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module that had to be enabled to show this information.